# how to make list of all neighbors in Python?

Tags: python, networkx

I have a list as below.
It consists of 2 columns which are 'HOME' and 'AWAY'.

```
Home     AWAY
Rangers  Twins
Yankees  RedSox
RedSox   Yankees
Cups     Yankees
```

I would like to make all neighborhood of each team regardless of home or away, such like below.

```
TEAM     NEIGHBOR
Rangers  [Twins]
Yankees  [RedSox, Cups]
RedSox   [Yankees]
Cups     [Yankees]
```

Though I considered use networks modules, I could not solve that problems.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution using networkx:

```
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='Home', target='AWAY')
for node in G.nodes():
    print(node, list(G.neighbors(node)))

#output:
Rangers ['Twins']
Twins ['Rangers']
Yankees ['RedSox', 'Cups']
RedSox ['Yankees']
Cups ['Yankees']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this without the usage of any 3rd-party libraries.

```
import sys
import json

def stackoverflow():
    matches = [
        {"Home": ["Rangers", "Yankees", "RedSox", "Cups"]},
        {"Away": ["Twins", "RedSox", "Yankees", "Yankees"]}
    ]

    matchups = []
    for ih, homeTeam in enumerate(matches[0]["Home"]):
        for ia, awayTeam in enumerate(matches[1]["Away"]):
            if ih == ia:
                matchups.append({homeTeam:awayTeam})

    schedule = {}
    for idx, match in enumerate(matchups):
        homeTeam, awayTeam = list(match.items())[0]
        # add all teams to the schedule.
        schedule[homeTeam] = []
        schedule[awayTeam] = []
    
    for team in schedule:
        for match in matchups:
            homeTeam, awayTeam = list(match.items())[0]
            if awayTeam not in schedule[homeTeam]:
                schedule[homeTeam].append(awayTeam)
            if homeTeam not in schedule[awayTeam]:
                schedule[awayTeam].append(homeTeam)

    print(json.dumps(schedule,sort_keys=True, indent=4))
    
stackoverflow()
```

> *What's happening?*
>
> - First we setup our matches
> - Then we create a dictionary of the matchups {HomeTeam : AwayTeam}
> - Then we check what teams are facing each-other and adding them to *that* teams entry of upcoming matches.

Output:

```
{
  "Cups": [
    "Yankees"
  ],
  "Rangers": [
    "Twins"
  ],
  "RedSox": [
    "Yankees"
  ],
  "Twins": [
    "Rangers"
  ],
  "Yankees": [
    "RedSox",
    "Cups"
  ]
}
```

*Without json-print*

```
{
 'Rangers': ['Twins'], 
 'Twins':   ['Rangers'], 
 'Yankees': ['RedSox', 'Cups'], 
 'RedSox':  ['Yankees'], 
 'Cups':    ['Yankees']
}
```